# Will Docker assist as a high level compressor?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a package sizing around 2+GB in an ubuntu machine. I have created a docker image from docker file and the size is around 86MB. Now, I have created another image by updating the docker file with the copy command which is to copy the package in the ubuntu machine to the docker image while building a new docker image.

Now, I am seeing the docker image size is around 2GB since the docker image contains the package as well. I want to know does this docker phenomena helps us in anyway to reduce the size of the package after making as a docker image.

I want the docker image to be created in such a way it should also contains the package which is around 2GB but I don't want docker image size should cross 200MB.

Regards,
Karthik

Answer (score 3):

Docker will not compress an image's data for you.  Hoping for 10x compression on an arbitrary installed package is rather optimistic, Docker or otherwise.

While Docker uses some clever and complicated kernel mechanisms, in most cases a file in a container maps to an ordinary file on disk in a strange filesystem layout.  If you're trying to install a 2 GB package into an image, it will require 2 GB of local disk space.  There are some mechanisms to share data that can help reduce overall disk usage (if you run 10 containers based on that image, they will share the 2 GB base image and not use extra disk space) but no built-in compression.

One further note: once you've taken action in a Dockerfile to use space in some form, it's permanently used.  Each line in the Dockerfile creates a new "layer" or separate image which records the changes from the previous layer.  If you're trying to install package that's not in a repository of some sort, you're stuck with its space utilization in the image, unless you can use multi-stage builds for it:

```sh
FROM ubuntu:18.04
COPY package.deb .
# At this point there is a layer containing the .deb file and
# it uses space in the final image.
RUN dpkg --install package.deb && rm package.deb
# The file isn't "in the image", but the image remembers adding it
# and then removing it, so it still uses space.
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by David it's not possible using docker which uses overlay or something similar layered FS representation.

But there is a workaround to keep the size of image low (but the size of the container will be big !!), but it'll increase the startup time of app from the docker container, also may add some complications to the arguments that you pass to the app. A possible way to reduce size :

- compress the package before adding
- copy the compressed one while building an image
- use some script as the ENTRYPOINT/CMD whatever you use to start the container which should perform

  - uncompression [you'll need the uncompression package installed in the container] and
  - start the application.(you can reuse the arguments received to docker run as $@ while passing to the application - or even validate the arguments beforehand)

Check by compressing your package file with gzip / 7zip / bzip2 or any compressor of your choice - all to see the output file is of reduced size.

If it can't be compressed enough

Comment: It will still intrinsically need the full size of the uncompressed content once the container starts up.  If you have multiple containers based on the image, they will each have a duplicate copy of the uncompressed large content.

Comment: yes, so only useful if the disk space is not issue. Only the network time to download the image will be low and the size. all runtime will happen for each container in different rw layer

Comment: @DavidMaze, by the way - will using different storage driver for dockerd (not sure if there is any driver that supports compression - like windows option of 'compress to reduce size' for the disk) chage anything on total size used in storing the containers?